# Selecting more than one attribute from xml file

Tags: xpath

I have an xml file. In the file there are some elements with some attributes.

I want to select the attributes age and height to put in a dropdown box. If I do the following, I get the age displayed in the drop-down box.

```
var q = this.test;
var a = (this.lastForm = isoNS.curForm).selectNodes("*[@COLNAME='AGE']"), g = a.length;

q.removeAll();
while(g--)q.add({isoCID: a[g].getAttribute("ISOCID"),
         label: a[g].getAttribute("COLNAME")});
```

To get the height displayed, I have tried the following (among other thing), but doesn't work

```
    var a = (this.lastForm = isoNS.curForm).selectNodes("*[@COLNAME='AGE' and @COLNAME='HEIGHT']"), g = a.length;
```

How do I get both values?

Comment: There should be OR instead of AND, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XML files with the same structure in your program, it is better to create a serializable class for it using "**Paste XML as classes**" command in Visual Studio. Then you will be able to operate it much easier, without getting tired with a hard-code approach like using Xpath